# do_IRQ: 0.163 No irq handler for vector (irq -1)

Tags: debian, syslog, irq

Why do I get this message in the terminal (putty) ?

```
Message from syslogd@Debian-87-jessie-64-minimal at May 27 01:14:25 ...
 kernel:[ 8242.806151] do_IRQ: 0.163 No irq handler for vector (irq -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue on a ASUS P5VD2-X motherboard. 
Fixed adding this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet pci=nomsi,noaer"
```

on

```
/etc/default/grub
```

and running `update-grub;reboot`

- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1234983